# CallBack method implementation needed

Tags: java, javafx

I have a root screen which generates a popup and in popup I have a listview with button on it and I want to update the texfield in root screen and close the popupwindow when a button is clicked in  popup. Code for popup and its controller.

POPUP

```
public void display() throws IOException {
Stage window =new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/ProfilePopup.fxml"));
        window.setTitle("Your profile");
        window.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 500));
        window.show();


    }
```

PopUPController

```
public void initialize() {
        listView.setEditable(true);

        listView.setVisible(true);
        listView.setItems(walletModel.myWallets);

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> {
            try {
                return new EditableCell();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        });
        listView.layout();


        addWalletButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            walletModel.createWallet();
            listView.getFixedCellSize();
            size.setText("Total Wallets:  " + walletModel.walletSize());
        });
        if (walletModel.myWallets.size() == 0) {
            walletModel.initializeWalletData();
            walletModel.myWallets.add(walletModel.initializeWalletData());
        }
        size.setText("Wallet Size " + walletModel.walletSize());
    }
    static class EditableCell extends ListCell<WalletModel.WalletData> {

        private final WalletCellController controller;


        EditableCell() throws IOException {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/selectButton.fxml"));
            Node graphic = loader.load();
            controller = loader.getController();
            setGraphic(graphic);

        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(WalletModel.WalletData item, boolean empty) {


            if (empty) {

                controller.rootView.setVisible(false);

            } else {
                controller.textField.setText(item.getName());
                controller.rootView.setVisible(true);


            }
        }
    }


}
```

I want the button on listview to update the root screen when its clicked and plus close the popup as well. Each listview is getting graphics from walletcellcontroller code below.
Here is how I am calling from the root screen.
Creating instance in root screen and then calling
(Popup popup=new Popup();)

```
public void popupOpen() throws IOException {
        popup.display();


    }
```

here is the code for listview item

```
public class WalletCellController implements OnClick {
    public Button select;
    public TextField textField;
    public AnchorPane rootView;
    public  void initialize(){
        onMouseClicked();
    }
    public void onMouseClicked() {

        select.setOnAction(closeEvent -> {
            Node source = (Node) closeEvent.getSource();
            Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        });



}}
```

Can you tell me how to use the callbacks for actionevents here. I think I need call back from POPUP Controller to POPup and then from POPup to root screen.
I am new in java so I not sure about the implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Callable {
public void callBackMethod();
}

class Worker {
// Worker gets a handle to the boss object via the Callable interface.
// There's no way this worker class can call any other method other than
// the one in Callable.
public void doSomeWork(Callable myBoss) {
    myBoss.callBackMethod();
    // ERROR!
    //myBoss.directMethod();
}
}

class Boss implements Callable {
public Boss() {
    // Boss creates a worker object, and tells it to do some work.
    Worker w1 = new Worker();
    // Notice, we're passing a reference of the boss to the worker.
    w1.doSomeWork(this);
}
//developer that develop library just call controll the place of calling

public void callBackMethod() {
    System.out.println("What do you want?");
}

public void directMethod() {
    System.out.println("I'm out for coffee.");
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Boss b = new Boss();
    b.directMethod();

    // write your code here
}
}
```

this is sample code of [call back method](https://github.com/MostafaAnter/CallBack/blob/master/src/com/mostafa/anter/Main.java)

Comment: thanks ,but do you understand my question, actually the callback chain is too complex in mine . So can you help?

Comment: U can understand my example and implement that on your case first define interface then make function that take instance of interface finally make class that call action event implement interface

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these I recommend using `Dialog`, since it allows you to query & wait for user input.

#### Example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Dialog?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<Dialog xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="dialog" fx:controller="fxml.DialogController">
    <dialogPane>
        <DialogPane headerText="Choose item!">
            <content>
                <VBox prefWidth="100" spacing="5">
                    <children>
                        <Button text="a" onAction="#choice" maxWidth="Infinity" />
                        <Button text="b" onAction="#choice" maxWidth="Infinity" />
                        <Button text="c" onAction="#choice" maxWidth="Infinity" />
                        <Button text="Cancel" onAction="#cancel" maxWidth="Infinity" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </DialogPane>
    </dialogPane>
</Dialog>
```

```
public class DialogController {
    @FXML
    private Dialog<String> dialog;

    @FXML
    private void choice(ActionEvent event) {
        Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
        dialog.setResult(source.getText());
        dialog.close();
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void cancel() {
        dialog.setResult("");
        dialog.close();
    }
    
}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    Button btn = new Button("Choose");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Dialog<String> dialog;
        try {
            dialog = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Dialog.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (!result.orElse("").isEmpty()) {
            textField.setText(s);
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(textField, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```